# In QGIS is it possible to apply an expression to a join

Tags: qgis, sql, attribute-joins, virtual-layer

I am trying to join by 2 text fields and there is a lot of mismatch due to CaSe and space issues... can it be run so that it's

```
lower("field1")=lower("field2")
```

I otherwise have to create a new field with this and as it's a repeated process I'd rather not.

If Virtual Layer is the answer -what's the SQL query to run?

```
SELECT from table1, table2
WHERE lower(table1.field1)=lower(table2.field2)
GROUP By field1
```

Ideally I'd like to use RE and remove extra spaces at the end as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a test example I used two dummy layers (Layer1, Layer2) as below.

- Layer1 --- [field1] GAMMA, alpha__, BEta_, epsilon, blue
- Layer2 --- [field2] Alpha, Beta__, Delta____, Gamma_, Epsilon

Underscores are the location where I added extra spaces.

And a Virtual Layer query:

```
SELECT * FROM Layer1
INNER JOIN Layer2 ON Lower(RTrim(Layer1.field1)) = Lower(RTrim(Layer2.field2))
```

Here `RTrim()` removes all tailing spaces.

Then it returns a combined table like:

[image]

SQLite `REGEXP` is beyond my ability. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to create virtual fields in both tables, and then use those fields for the join.  Virtual fields were added in QGIS 2.6; they don't modify (clutter) the underlying data source, and only exist within the scope of your QGIS project.

To create a virtual field, use the field calculator:

[image: adding a virtual field]

You can do this in both tables as needed.  The expressions can be as simple or as complex as you need them to be.  Once added, you can then use them in the regular "join" dialog.